# Android notification custom sound not playing

Tags: android, firebase

I want a custom `mp3` sound to play when my notification pops up. This is my code:

```
public class firebase_connection extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage message) {
        String title = Objects.requireNonNull(message.getNotification()).getTitle();
        String body = message.getNotification().getBody();
        Uri sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/music.mp3");
        super.onMessageReceived(message);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("MyNotifications","MyNotifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            AudioAttributes aud_att = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                    .build();
            channel.setSound(sound,aud_att);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

            Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this,"MyNotifications")
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(1,notification.build());
        }
    }
}
```

---

The `mp3` file is located in `res->raw->music.mp3`. Upon executing the code, the notification shows with the default sound. Why? Where am I going wrong? Please help me.

Also I am getting this message in my logcat:

> W/FirebaseMessaging: Missing Default Notification Channel metadata in
> AndroidManifest. Default value will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try once this solutions

```
   val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        
        Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this,"MyNotifications")
                            .setContentTitle(title)
                            .setContentText(body)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            **.setSound(defaultSoundUri)// Try your Sound here** 
                            .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Comment: `notification.setSound()` is deprecated. You have to use `setSound()` on the notification channel